# Kotlin testing the restriction in DSL

Tags: testing, kotlin, compilation, kotlin-dsl

We are writing a DSL in Kotlin, and we have added a few restrictions in that DSL.
For eg,

```
table {
  tr {
    td {
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we restrict `td` should not be called inside another `td`.

How do we test this? Is there any dsl-testkit or matcher library in kotlin that lets us do something like "shouldNot compile" does in [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingThatCodeDoesNotCompile)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the Kotlin scripting engine, make it run a script with your DSL constructs that should be rejected and assert that the script didn't compile.

Links that you may find useful:

- [Run Kotlin Scripts (kts) from regular Kotlin programs](https://kotlinexpertise.com/run-kotlin-scripts-from-kotlin-programs/) by Kotlin Expertise Blog
- [`s1monw1/KtsRunner`](https://github.com/s1monw1/KtsRunner), a library that encapsulates running Kotlin scripts programmatically
- A newer and more powerful, though more complex scripting support implementation on the Kotlin side is described in [KEEP-75](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md#how-to-implement-scripting-support)